# Set of linear operators problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S be a set of linear operators $ \in L(\mathbb{C^3}) $ so that no two linear operators are similar and so that 
$$ A^{10} +3*A^9 +2*A^8 = 0 , \forall A  \in S $$
How many elements can S contain? 
I tried by looking at similarity invariants but don't really know what elements of S look like

Comment: Can you infer anything from $A^{10}+3A^9+2A^8=A^8(A+2I)(A+I)=0$?

Comment: Then S would contain three linear operators whose matrixes are the solutions of the equation? The three matrixes are not similar because they have different determinants?

Comment: Not only three. $A^8=0$ does not only imply $A=0$. $A$ can be nilpotent.

Comment: Also yes for your second question. Similar matrices have same determinants. But the converse is not true.

Comment: Seems to me, that uin this case there are not that many nilpotent operators - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix